# How do I enable All UART Ports at Boot?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, uart, imx6

On my embedded system there is a Real Time Clock (RTC) connected to uart 2.

```
21e8000.serial: ttymxc1 at MMIO 0x21e8000 (irq = 59, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
```

I have written a rtc kernel driver that uses  filp_open("/dev/ttymxc1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC, 0) to communicate with the RTC.  After I boot and log in everything works great.  hwclock does what it is supposed to.  The problem is during boot the filp_open returns a -2 /* ENOENT - No such file or directory */.

```
silhouettestar2_rtc rtc.24: RTC-SilhouetteStar2: file open error = -2
```

My rtc_read_time function is getting called twice during boot and both times the same error is returned.  Dmesg is showing me the uart drivers are loaded before the RTC driver.  I have the suspition that ttymxc1 is not enabled yet.  Can ttymxc1 get enabled when the driver is loaded like the console?  Is there another interface that can be used in the kernel module to communicate directly with ttymxc1?

```
$> dmesg    
    [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
    [    0.000000] Linux version 3.14.79+g5dcba44 (schustercp@Ubuntu-Dev2) (gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue May 1 15:46:06 NZST 2018
    [    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [412fc09a] revision 10 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
    [    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
    [    0.000000] Machine model: ARANZ SilhouetteStar with i.MX6 Solo/DualLite
    [    0.000000] cma: dma_contiguous_reserve(limit 50000000)
    [    0.000000] cma: dma_contiguous_reserve: reserving 256 MiB for global area
    [    0.000000] cma: cma_declare_contiguous(size 10000000, base 00000000, limit 50000000 alignment 00000000)
    [    0.000000] cma: CMA: reserved 256 MiB at 40000000
    [    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
    [    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 262144
    [    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat 807cf000, node_mem_map af777000
    [    0.000000]   DMA zone: 2048 pages used for memmap
    [    0.000000]   DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
    [    0.000000]   DMA zone: 262144 pages, LIFO batch:31
    [    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 7 pages/cpu @af754000 s8192 r8192 d12288 u32768
    [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s8192 r8192 d12288 u32768 alloc=8*4096
    [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 
    [    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 260096
    [    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttymxc0,115200,115200 quiet coherent_pool=180M root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait ro rootfstype=ext4
    [    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
    [    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
    [    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
    [    0.000000] Memory: 768360K/1048576K available (5516K kernel code, 233K rwdata, 1876K rodata, 336K init, 399K bss, 280216K reserved, 0K highmem)
    [    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
        vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
        fixmap  : 0xfff00000 - 0xfffe0000   ( 896 kB)
        vmalloc : 0xc0800000 - 0xff000000   (1000 MB)
        lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0xc0000000   (1024 MB)
        pkmap   : 0x7fe00000 - 0x80000000   (   2 MB)
        modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x7fe00000   (  14 MB)
          .text : 0x80008000 - 0x80740534   (7394 kB)
          .init : 0x80741000 - 0x80795000   ( 336 kB)
          .data : 0x80796000 - 0x807d04a0   ( 234 kB)
           .bss : 0x807d04a8 - 0x8083448c   ( 400 kB)
    [    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=2, Nodes=1
    [    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
    [    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=4 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
    [    0.000000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=2
    [    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
    [    0.000000] L2C-310 erratum 769419 enabled
    [    0.000000] L2C-310 enabling early BRESP for Cortex-A9
    [    0.000000] L2C-310 cache controller enabled, 16 ways, 512 kB
    [    0.000000] L2C-310: CACHE_ID 0x410000c8, AUX_CTRL 0x72450000
    [    0.000000] Switching to timer-based delay loop
    [    0.000008] sched_clock: 32 bits at 3000kHz, resolution 333ns, wraps every 1431655765682ns
    [    0.000980] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 6.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=30000)
    [    0.000992] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
    [    0.001165] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
    [    0.001175] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
    [    0.007102] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
    [    0.007371] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
    [    0.007450] Setting up static identity map for 0x1053ef70 - 0x1053efc8
    [    0.008959] CPU1: Booted secondary processor
    [    0.008987] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
    [    0.009096] Brought up 2 CPUs
    [    0.009107] SMP: Total of 2 processors activated (12.00 BogoMIPS).
    [    0.009112] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
    [    0.009757] devtmpfs: initialized
    [    0.013214] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant 9 rev 4
    [    0.026956] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
    [    0.027224] regulator-dummy: no parameters
    [    0.027501] NET: Registered protocol family 16
    [    0.028182] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 46080, align 8)
    [    0.048082] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afd77000
    [    0.730786] DMA: preallocated 184320 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
    [    0.731204] cpuidle: using governor ladder
    [    0.731211] cpuidle: using governor menu
    [    0.731330] CPU identified as i.MX6DL, silicon rev 1.1
    [    0.731428] Use WDOG1 as reset source
    [    0.739809] syscon 20c8000.anatop: regmap [mem 0x020c8000-0x020c8fff] registered
    [    0.740120] vdd1p1: 800 <--> 1375 mV at 1100 mV 
    [    0.740430] vdd3p0: 2800 <--> 3150 mV at 3000 mV 
    [    0.740789] vdd2p5: 2000 <--> 2750 mV at 2400 mV 
    [    0.741128] vddarm: 725 <--> 1450 mV at 1150 mV 
    [    0.750683] vddpu: 725 <--> 1450 mV at 1150 mV 
    [    0.751032] vddsoc: 725 <--> 1450 mV at 1175 mV 
    [    0.753291] syscon 20e0000.iomuxc-gpr: regmap [mem 0x020e0000-0x020e0037] registered
    [    0.755630] syscon 21bc000.ocotp-ctrl: regmap [mem 0x021bc000-0x021bffff] registered
    [    0.759444] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
    [    0.759452] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
    [    0.761410] imx6dl-pinctrl 20e0000.iomuxc: initialized IMX pinctrl driver
    [    0.770481] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
    [    0.772859] mxs-dma 110000.dma-apbh: initialized
    [    0.773567] brcm_osc_reg: 3300 mV 
    [    0.773828] brcm_reg: 3300 mV 
    [    0.774027] 3P3V: 3300 mV 
    [    0.774234] usb_otg_vbus: 5000 mV 
    [    0.774490] reg_boost_aux: 5000 mV 
    [    0.774760] reg_cam: 2800 mV 
    [    0.775451] SCSI subsystem initialized
    [    0.775631] libata version 3.00 loaded.
    [    0.775880] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
    [    0.775941] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
    [    0.776035] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
    [    0.776192] usbphy_nop1.10 supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
    [    0.776258] usbphy_nop2.11 supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
    [    0.777491] i2c i2c-0: IMX I2C adapter registered
    [    0.777866] i2c i2c-1: IMX I2C adapter registered
    [    0.777974] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
    [    0.778018] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
    [    0.778023] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
    [    0.778042] PTP clock support registered
    [    0.790721] imx-ipuv3 2400000.ipu: IPU DMFC NORMAL mode: 1(0~1), 5B(4,5), 5F(6,7)
    [    0.791800] mxc_mipi_csi2 21dc000.mipi_csi: i.MX MIPI CSI2 driver probed
    [    0.791811] mxc_mipi_csi2 21dc000.mipi_csi: i.MX MIPI CSI2 dphy version is 0x3130302a
    [    0.791874] MIPI CSI2 driver module loaded
    [    0.791942] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
    [    0.792873] Switched to clocksource mxc_timer1
    [    0.794795] NET: Registered protocol family 2
    [    0.795497] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
    [    0.795576] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
    [    0.795703] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
    [    0.795843] TCP: reno registered
    [    0.795855] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
    [    0.795892] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
    [    0.796150] NET: Registered protocol family 1
    [    0.796438] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
    [    0.796444] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
    [    0.796448] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
    [    0.796453] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
    [    0.796908] hw perfevents: enabled with ARMv7 Cortex-A9 PMU driver, 7 counters available
    [    0.798888] Bus freq driver module loaded
    [    0.799778] futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
    [    0.808299] zbud: loaded
    [    0.808637] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
    [    0.808935] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
    [    0.811123] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
    [    0.811162] Key type id_resolver registered
    [    0.811166] Key type id_legacy registered
    [    0.811398] fuse init (API version 7.22)
    [    0.811899] msgmni has been set to 2012
    [    0.814579] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 250)
    [    0.814589] io scheduler noop registered
    [    0.814593] io scheduler deadline registered
    [    0.814814] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
    [    0.816425] imx-sdma 20ec000.sdma: no iram assigned, using external mem
    [    0.816443] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 1, align 0)
    [    0.817803] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afedf000
    [    0.817851] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 1, align 0)
    [    0.818412] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afedf020
    [    0.818460] imx-sdma 20ec000.sdma: no event needs to be remapped
    [    0.818600] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 1, align 0)
    [    0.819179] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afedf040
    [    0.819292] cma: cma_release(page afedf040)
    [    0.819306] imx-sdma 20ec000.sdma: loaded firmware 3.1
    [    0.822617] imx-sdma 20ec000.sdma: initialized
    [    0.823223] Serial: IMX driver
    [    0.823492] 2020000.serial: ttymxc0 at MMIO 0x2020000 (irq = 58, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
    [    0.823637] console [ttymxc0] enabled
    [    0.824366] 21e8000.serial: ttymxc1 at MMIO 0x21e8000 (irq = 59, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
    [    0.824836] 21f0000.serial: ttymxc3 at MMIO 0x21f0000 (irq = 61, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
    [    0.825166] serial: Freescale lpuart driver
    [    0.826280] imx sema4 driver is registered.
    [    0.826321] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
    [    0.826690] [drm] Initialized vivante 1.0.0 20120216 on minor 0
    [    0.834551] brd: module loaded
    [    0.838664] loop: module loaded
    [    0.840265] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
    [    0.840342] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
    [    0.841090] 2184800.usbmisc supply vbus-wakeup not found, using dummy regulator
    [    0.844951] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 1, align 0)
    [    0.845655] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afedf040
    [    0.847848] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
    [    0.848631] silhouettestar2_rtc rtc.24: RTC-SilhouetteStar2 Probe
    [    0.848669] silhouettestar2_rtc rtc.24: RTC-SilhouetteStar2 Get Time
    [    0.848703] silhouettestar2_rtc rtc.24: RTC-SilhouetteStar2: file open error = -2
    [    0.855154] silhouettestar2_rtc rtc.24: rtc core: registered rtc.24 as rtc0
    [    0.855195] i2c /dev entries driver
    [    0.856658] imx2-wdt 20bc000.wdog: IMX2+ Watchdog Timer enabled. timeout=60s (nowayout=0)
    [    0.856898] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
    [    0.856902] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
    [    0.856907] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
    [    0.858740] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 1, align 0)
    [    0.859396] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afedf060
    [    0.859450] mmc1: no vqmmc regulator found
    [    1.162907] mmc1: SDHCI controller on 2190000.usdhc [2190000.usdhc] using ADMA
    [    1.165494] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 1, align 0)
    [    1.170216] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afedf080
    [    1.172928] mmc0: no vqmmc regulator found
    [    1.173269] 2194000.usdhc supply card-external-vcc not found, using dummy regulator
    [    1.186120] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
    [    1.187813] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
    [    1.189509] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
    [    1.192539] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
    [    1.195577] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
    [    1.245767] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
    [    1.272904] mmc0: SDHCI controller on 2194000.usdhc [2194000.usdhc] using ADMA
    [    1.273425] galcore: clk_get vg clock failed, disable vg!
    [    1.273446] Galcore version 5.0.11.25762
    [    1.322143] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch. assuming write-enable.
    [    1.329647] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 0007
    [    1.330377] mmcblk0: mmc0:0007 SD08G 7.21 GiB 
    [    1.334584]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3 p4 < p5 p6 p7 >
    [    1.594994] mxc_vdoa 21e4000.vdoa: i.MX Video Data Order Adapter(VDOA) driver probed
    [    1.595518] mxc_vpu 2040000.vpu: VPU initialized
    [    1.596267] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
    [    1.843486] caam 2100000.caam: Instantiated RNG4 SH0
    [    2.087961] caam 2100000.caam: Instantiated RNG4 SH1
    [    2.087973] caam 2100000.caam: device ID = 0x0a160100 (Era 4)
    [    2.087983] caam 2100000.caam: job rings = 2, qi = 0
    [    2.088433] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 1, align 0)
    [    2.089464] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afedf160
    [    2.089504] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 1, align 0)
    [    2.090342] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afedf180
    [    2.113030] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 1, align 0)
    [    2.113915] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afedf1a0
    [    2.113953] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 1, align 0)
    [    2.114797] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afedf1c0
    [    2.145816] caam algorithms registered in /proc/crypto
    [    2.149413] caam_jr 2101000.jr0: registering rng-caam
    [    2.152441] snvs-secvio 20cc000.caam-snvs: violation handlers armed - non-secure state
    [    2.152733] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
    [    2.152738] usbhid: USB HID core driver
    [    2.155249] TCP: cubic registered
    [    2.155950] NET: Registered protocol family 10
    [    2.156836] sit: IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
    [    2.157536] NET: Registered protocol family 17
    [    2.157597] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
    [    2.157647] Key type dns_resolver registered
    [    2.158776] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
    [    2.159338] reg_cam: disabling
    [    2.159354] regulator-dummy: disabling
    [    2.159603] imx mcc test is registered.
    [    2.159961] silhouettestar2_rtc rtc.24: RTC-SilhouetteStar2 Get Time
    [    2.159997] silhouettestar2_rtc rtc.24: RTC-SilhouetteStar2: file open error = -2
    [    2.166212] silhouettestar2_rtc rtc.24: hctosys: unable to read the hardware clock
    [    2.174066] ALSA device list:
    [    2.174070]   No soundcards found.
    [    2.193357] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    [    2.193388] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
    [    2.197512] devtmpfs: mounted
    [    2.198079] Freeing unused kernel memory: 336K (80741000 - 80795000)
    [    2.430273] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 21 bits of entropy available)
    [    2.443943] systemd[1]: systemd 219 running in system mode. (-PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP -LIBCRYPTSETUP -GCRYPT -GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID -ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN)
    [    2.444442] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
    [    2.445565] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <SilhouetteStar_2010-01_L16X00000>.
    [    2.452569] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 21 bits of entropy available)
    [    2.452687] systemd[1]: Initializing machine ID from random generator.
    [    2.453256] systemd[1]: Installed transient /etc/machine-id file.
    [    2.466457] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 21 bits of entropy available)
    [    2.495941] random: systemd-sysv-ge: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 22 bits of entropy available)
    [    2.559118] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 24 bits of entropy available)
    [    2.559338] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 24 bits of entropy available)
    [    2.560660] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 24 bits of entropy available)
    [    2.560977] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 24 bits of entropy available)
    [    2.561545] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 24 bits of entropy available)
    [    2.566338] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 24 bits of entropy available)
    [    2.694349] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit org.freedesktop.resolve1.busname, ignoring: Unit org.freedesktop.resolve1.busname failed to load: No such file or directory.
    [    2.697889] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
    [    2.697956] systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
    [    2.698137] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
    [    2.698192] systemd[1]: Starting Remote File Systems.
    [    2.698407] systemd[1]: Created slice Root Slice.
    [    2.698467] systemd[1]: Starting Root Slice.
    [    2.698705] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
    [    2.698763] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket (/dev/log).
    [    2.698974] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
    [    2.699052] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket.
    [    2.699212] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
    [    2.699265] systemd[1]: Starting Syslog Socket.
    [    2.719414] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
    [    2.719659] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
    [    2.719721] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Socket.
    [    2.719986] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
    [    2.720046] systemd[1]: Starting /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
    [    2.720262] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
    [    2.720319] systemd[1]: Starting udev Control Socket.
    [    2.720707] systemd[1]: Listening on networkd rtnetlink socket.
    [    2.720767] systemd[1]: Starting networkd rtnetlink socket.
    [    2.721055] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
    [    2.721138] systemd[1]: Starting System Slice.
    [    2.722708] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
    [    2.723314] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
    [    2.723825] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
    [    2.724328] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
    [    2.724394] systemd[1]: Starting system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
    [    2.728044] systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
    [    2.728352] systemd[1]: Mounted Configuration File System.
    [    2.729944] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
    [    2.732610] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
    [    2.733011] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
    [    2.736793] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
    [    2.737450] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
    [    2.737564] systemd[1]: Starting system-getty.slice.
    [    2.739864] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
    [    2.740495] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
    [    2.740614] systemd[1]: Starting system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
    [    2.743319] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
    [    2.775409] systemd[1]: Mounting Temporary Directory...
    [    2.778634] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
    [    2.778700] systemd[1]: Starting User and Session Slice.
    [    2.778800] systemd[1]: Started Setup Virtual Console.
    [    2.779737] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
    [    2.779797] systemd[1]: Starting Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
    [    2.779877] systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
    [    2.779918] systemd[1]: Starting Paths.
    [    2.780229] systemd[1]: Created slice system-wpa_supplicant.slice.
    [    2.780276] systemd[1]: Starting system-wpa_supplicant.slice.
    [    2.780472] systemd[1]: Listening on Delayed Shutdown Socket.
    [    2.780518] systemd[1]: Starting Delayed Shutdown Socket.
    [    2.780604] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
    [    2.780647] systemd[1]: Starting Swap.
    [    2.780729] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
    [    2.780772] systemd[1]: Starting Slices.
    [    2.781935] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
    [    2.793687] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
    [    2.793859] systemd[1]: Mounted Temporary Directory.
    [    2.823354] systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
    [    2.834004] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
    [    2.862172] systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
    [    2.882042] systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
    [    2.958417] systemd[1]: Started Rebuild Hardware Database.
    [    2.958548] systemd[1]: Started First Boot Wizard.
    [    2.958620] systemd[1]: Started Create System Users.
    [    2.960200] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
    [    2.960396] systemd[1]: Started Rebuild Dynamic Linker Cache.
    [    2.996235] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
    [    3.498541] mxc_v4l_open: Mxc Camera no sensor ipu0/csi0
    [    3.635806] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
    [    3.816727] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
    [    3.881444] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Jan 23 2013 17:47:32 version 5.90.195.114 FWID 01-f9e7e464
    [    4.188236] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    [    4.377138] systemd-journald[144]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
    [    4.534245] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    [    4.933892] using random self ethernet address
    [    4.933906] using random host ethernet address
    [    4.934572] usb0: HOST MAC 6e:9f:55:e3:b3:86
    [    4.934626] usb0: MAC 9a:2d:f9:b9:90:d9
    [    4.934659] using random self ethernet address
    [    4.934668] using random host ethernet address
    [    4.934708] g_ether gadget: Ethernet Gadget, version: Memorial Day 2008
    [    4.934714] g_ether gadget: g_ether ready
    [    5.337972] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): usb0: link is not ready
    [    5.982973] mxc_v4l2_master_attach: ipu0:/csi0 mipi attached ov5640_mipi:mxc_v4l2_cap0
    [    5.983000] camera ov5640_mipi is found
    [    8.459218] g_ether gadget: high-speed config #1: CDC Ethernet (ECM)
    [    8.460691] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): usb0: link becomes ready
    [   11.674988] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 1, align 0)
    [   11.676195] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afedf1e0
    [   11.676250] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 20, align 5)
    [   11.676940] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afedf400
    [   11.677386] cma: cma_alloc(cma 8081d358, count 1, align 0)
    [   11.678082] cma: cma_alloc(): returned afedf200
```

Comment: Why did you write the program as a kernel driver and not in user space? The problem may be in that the /dev/tty* may be created by udev(systemd) and it is too late for your module because your module is starting before systemd.

Comment: If there is a RTC driver registered linux sets the system time from the registered RTC module very early during boot.  You may be correct about the /dev/tty*.  That is why and am searching for another interface to the uart.  I am going through the serial_core.c and imx.c trying to figure out exactly how the serial framework in the kernel works.  There is an RTC on the iMX6 but hardware engineers figured it was best to not keep that RTC powered :(

Comment: I would try to port or hack existing ttymxc1 serial driver as a external driver and inside it do the things. As a workaround you could also modify your current driver and wait in some thread for appearance of /dev/ttymxc1 file but don't recommend it.

Comment: Your design is simple wrong. There should not be anything like `filp_open()` in it.

Comment: I never did figure this out. In the end, I removed the RTC drivers / subsystem from my defconfig and set the system time in an application that is started by systemd after the UARTS are up. I would have much rather have let the Kernel RTC manage this. Now I will always have time jumps in most of the different service log files including syslog.